# Make zsh tab-complete path after colon

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

To quickly and temporarily append a directory to my `PATH` environment variable I usually do `export PATH=$PATH:/some/other/dir` however `zsh` does not tab-complete the part after the colon typing `:/so<tab>`. 
Typing `export PATH=/so <tab>` expands to `export PATH=/some/`

In `zsh` the tab-completion works after the `=` but not after the `:`.
How can I make `zsh` treat the colon as start of a new word where tab-completion can take place?

**edit-update**:
I just found out that it is **not** the `=` or `:` that prevent tab-complete. When trying to expand `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/Foo<tab>` the path is also not expanded.

I know about the `vared path` and I think its cool but my often enough my old bash habits kick in...

Here is the zsh-part of my `~/.zshrc`:

```
# The following lines were added by compinstall

zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _ignored
zstyle ':completion:*' max-errors 1
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/ruschi/.zshrc'

autoload -U promptinit && promptinit
autoload -Uz colors && colors
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit


# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt appendhistory extendedglob notify
#make zsh use emacs-style keybindings
bindkey -e
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install

# fix <ALT>arrow combinations
bindkey ";3D" emacs-backward-word                       
bindkey ";3C" emacs-forward-word
```

Comment: Such completions work for me; I'm afraid I don't know what options or styles I might have (or you don't have) that make it so, but it is possible.

Comment: Try starting with an unconfigured zsh by running zsh -f. Then add your configuration. At least the compinit line. That line should be the only thing needed to make it work. Perhaps there's something in a system /etc/zshrc.